# 64 Bit Integers in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I read several places in the Neo4j documents that suggest Neo4j supports 64bit integers. So I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting rounded values for large integer properties. For example:

```
CREATE (t:Test {id:9223372036854775807}) return t
```

results in:

> { "id": 9223372036854776000

I'm using both the Python 3 Bolt driver and the web console with community version 3.2.2.

What's going on? So I need to do something special to save large ints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neo4j uses 64-bit longs and doubles under the hood. We do have a bug affecting browser display of some long values in versions 3.2.1 and 3.2.2, but you should be seeing correct values on the python bolt driver.

EDIT: Also affects 3.2.3.

3.2.4 was pulled, so ignore that one...confirmed fixed for 3.2.5.

Comment: Thanks - I figured out that Bolt was working correctly last night. Glad to know it's just browser issue.